# How to design an class d output filter ( active filter )?

Tags: filter, signals, signal-processing, dac

I want to filter output of my full-bridge class d power amp. 
I'm trying to connect an ideal differential op to class d output for simulation.
But class d output through ideal differential op , growing noise floor(5~10dB).
I suspect that problem is incorrect op/filter connection. (pic. A)
[pic.A](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AuywF.png)

First, I'm mapping circuit(pic. A) to spectre(use one VCVS(pic. B) or two VCVS(pic. C)).
I'm trying 2 connections below:

[pic. B one VCVS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SXpgv.png)
    class d output SNDR is 96dB, op(ideal, gain: 100000) out is 82 dB
    problem is that op is ideal, 96dB to 82dB doesn't make sense.

[pic. C two VCVS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mm728.png)
    class d output SNDR is 96dB, op(ideal, gain: 100000) out is 74 dB
    problem is that op is ideal, 96dB to 74dB doesn't make sense.

I think SNDR of ideal differential op output, sholdn't decrease much.

Does the connection of op(pic.B or pic.C) is correct?
Any suggestion?

Comment: StackOverflow if for programming questions. You might have more luck trying https://electronics.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Would you mind deleting the question here if you ask it there, especially since cross posting has to be avoided?